# Has anyone been suspended for flopping?

Tags: basketball, nba, suspension

The league fines players for flopping and flopping can also be grounds for a technical foul. While players have been fined for flopping in games throughout the past few years, I want to know if anyone's ever been suspended for repeated flopping offences?

Comment: They have to get to at least five offences (six if the warning is included) so I'm going to say it's very unlikely. Nothing in a good Google comes up either.

Comment: @Nij I'd say that is an answer, particularly if you add the reference indicating why you say 5 offences is required.

Comment: Various articles talking about the introduction of penalties, easy enough to find if anybody wants to write the partial answer, but until I can get hold of a decent database of suspensions with reason listed since then, I'm wary of starting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [NBA.com](http://www.nba.com/2012/news/10/03/nba-sets-flopping-penalties.ap/), you must be charged with flopping 6 times or more to be suspended for flopping.

> Players will get a warning the first time, then be fined $5,000 for a second violation. The fines increase to $10,000 for a third offense, $15,000 for a fourth and $30,000 the fifth time. Six or more could lead to a suspension.

According to this list of [fines and suspensions](https://www.eskimo.com/~pbender/fines.html#16-17), if I counted correctly, there have been 36 fines handed out for flopping, but no suspensions.